# validating the sum of inputs in text area

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have  form that adds 6 user inputs. I want to have an alert if the total is not 100 or the user enters something other than a number. The alert works for a total greater than 100, but how do you check if it's less than 100 and all the inputs have been filled in? Right now I get the alert when the first input is being filled in.

```
<form name="myForm" id="form1">
                      <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" /> <br>
                     <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" /><br>
                     <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3" /><br>
                      <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" /> <br>
                      <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5" /><br>
                     <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6" /><br>


                    <textarea type="text" name="total" id="total" min="100" max="100" readonly></textarea>  
              </form>



    <script>
        function findTotal(){
                "use strict";
                var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
                var tot=0;
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                    if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
                        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

                    }
                }

                document.getElementById('total').value = tot;

                if (tot > 100) {            
                alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
                document.getElementById("qty1").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty2").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty3").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty4").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty5").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty6").value = null;
                document.getElementById("total").value = null;
                return false;
            }

        if (tot < 100) {            
                alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
                document.getElementById("qty1").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty2").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty3").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty4").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty5").value = null;
                document.getElementById("qty6").value = null;
                document.getElementById("total").value = null;
                return false;
            }

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: your code got cliffed off..Please update HTML code

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option
1. Use onkeyup function to check whether input is number or not
2. Use if(tot >100) condition to check value greater than 100
3. if(tot <100) condition to check value less than 100 and alert placed on last field to avoid alert on every field
4.Clear values if conditions are met

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" id="form1">
  <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" onkeyup="checkinput(this)" /> <br>
  <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" onkeyup="checkinput(this)" /><br>
  <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3" onkeyup="checkinput(this)" /><br>
  <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" onkeyup="checkinput(this)" /> <br>
  <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5" onkeyup="checkinput(this)" /><br>
  <input oninput="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6" onkeyup="checkinput(this)" /><br>


  <textarea type="text" name="total" id="total" min="100" max="100" readonly></textarea>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function findTotal() {
  "use strict";

  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

    }
  }

  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
  if (tot > 100) {
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].value = null;
    }
  }

  if (tot < 100 && arr[5].value) {
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].value = null;
    }
  }

}

function checkinput(x) {
  var y = x.value

  var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (y.match(regex)) {} else {
    alert("Enter number");
    x.value = '';
  }

}
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rLKkBb

Answer (score 0):

Your code has been cliffed off, but just so you know this:

```
if (tot > 100) {
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100"); 
    return false; 
}
if (tot < 100) { 
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100"); 
    return false; 
}
```

Is the same as writing this:

```
if(tot !== 100) {
    alert("Please make sure numbers total 100"); 
    return false;
}
```

### Edit:

It's because your event is firing on the oninput event, which fires every time a user types. Use the on submit event which fires when the form is submitted. Make sure to prevent default actions. Comment if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, the alert pops up before the user has input all the values because the number is less than 100. How do you use the code above and ensure that all the input fields have been populated?

Comment: Edited. That will stop the event from firing before the user presses the submit button, but you still have to validate input.

Comment: I tried the using on submit instead of on input, but no result.

Comment: Thats cause your form has no submit button

Answer (score -1):

One way you may be able to solve this is to exit out of the program if you can't parse all the inputs to ints.  If the default value can be parsed to an int, then you may need to add a special case.  Edit : Just replace the "return false" with whatever you want to happen when the user enters a non-integer value.

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) {
       tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);

    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I understand. How would the total value be validated with the above. I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Since parseInt returns NaN if the input cannot be parsed to an integer, any non-integer inputs should trigger the else, and cause the program to exit before it does anything.  (NaN is a falsy value)